# PHP variable causing browser error

Tags: php, apache, runtime-error

I have the following line of code:

```
$all_charity_discounts = array_merge($charity_discounts, $charity_discount_codes);
```

The first array has one value in it (another array), the other is empty. When this code is run, Chrome and Firefox produce a "This web page is not available"/"The connection was reset" error.

I cannot understand why this is happening. To make it weirder, the following also happens:

- Adding a new line above this line (can be an empty line, or a comment) fixes it
- Changing the variable name from $all_charity_discounts to $all_charity_discount fixes it
- Changing the variable name from $all_charity_discounts to $_all_charity_discounts fixes it
- Changing the variable name from $all_charity_discounts to $all_charity_discountsx fixes it
- Changing the variable name from $all_charity_discounts to $all_charity_discountx still breaks it

I am running a WAMP environment on Windows 7, using PHP 5.3.10 and Apache 2.2.1. The file is encoded to UTF-8 and I have tried using Sublime Text 3 and Notepad++.

I get these errors in my apache error log when the error occurs:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext/php_ffmpeg.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0g PHP/5.3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext/php_ffmpeg.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext/php_ffmpeg.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0
```

However, I'm not sure why this variable would trigger these sorts of errors.

Comment: PHP is server side script. It should throw an error in all browsers, not just in those 2.

Comment: Can you post the entire script? It would be helpful in diagnosing some of the oddities you're encountering.

Comment: Did you check if that dll actually exists?

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating your wamp or

You need to set both error_reporting and display_errors. These can be set in php.ini, in Apache (if you're using PHP as an Apache module) or during run-time, though if you set it during run-time then it won't effect some types of errors, such as parse errors.

For portability - that is, if you want to set this in the application - try setting them in an .htaccess:

```
# note: PHP constants such as E_ALL can't be used when setting it in Apache
php_value error_reporting 2147483647

php_flag display_errors on
```